# How to change Apple Watch app icon?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch

I looked into `Info.plist` of the *Watch Kit Extension* but there is nothing about the icon. Also the `Images.xcassets` is empty. Probably I am missing something really simple.

How can I change the icon of the Apple Watch icon shown in the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The image asset for the icon is in your WatchKit **app** and not the WatchKit extension. Look for the image asset named AppIcon in your watch app's asset catalog.

Answer (score 1):

your app's image asset catalog has app icon sizes for everything -incl watch

Answer (score 1):

Even though I had my images in the WatchKit App's xcasset's folder, it wouldn't pull in the AppIcon, instead going for the icon with the same name in the main app's folder. If you're still not seeing the icon appear, try changing the name of the WatchKit App icon to something unique. Then in your app's targets be sure to specify the new icon's location.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
*I learned the hard way the method I described below does not work. If you try to submit by doing that, you will get a bunch of errors. I'll leave it here so nobody makes the same mistake.*

For the sake of simplicity (having 1 `Images.xcassets` folder), I deleted the `Images.xcassets` folders that are created when you create a watch app, I then went into my existing `Images.xcassets` and added the new images (you can do this by enabling Apple Watch icon in Attribute Inspector). Then I just included this folder for the Apple Watch app target (not the extension target).

By having done this I can see the icon show up in the Apple Watch app for my app (you may need to reset simulator for it to show up).

The only downside to this approach is that it will add the unused icons to your watch app, which will increase the size of the app file. For my case the added size is less than 1 MB, so it is not a huge deal.